# Changing url of webview from another viewcontroller in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, webview, swift3, viewcontroller

I'm struggling with a situation where I want to reload a `webview` in `Main ViewController` when I click on a cell tab on another viewController. Actually another viewController is a slide menu controller. When I click that cell, I want to reload the `webview` which is located in `MainViewController` with new url which actually brings me to login webpage.

Please provide a solution in Swift 3.

Anyone help ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use the delegate to pass the new URL and load the web view

Comment: would you please help me in more specific way. with example and code snippets ?

Comment: refer this site to know about delegates https://blog.bobthedeveloper.io/the-complete-understanding-of-swift-delegate-and-data-source-9c91ecd7f1

Answer (score 0):

I feel that you should use between your WebView and ViewController with Table View delegate pattern [tutorial](https://www.google.pl/search?q=delegate%20pattern%20ios&oq=delegate%20pattern%20ios&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2961j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

it will also works by using NSNotificationCenter ([tutorial](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/08/fundamentals-of-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift/)) - but I don't recommend this solution for you personally

Answer (score 0):

Add this code into viewDidLoad method of your viewController which had webview

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reloadWebView), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
```

Add below function in the same viewController

```
    func reloadWebView(){
        //reload your webview here
    }
```

When ever slide menu selection happens on Slide ViewController call below code.

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
```